# How can I identify a mystery tray icon in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, process, icons, notification-area

A new icon has appeared in my tray in Windows 7 recently - a black square with a white A in it:

[image]

It doesn't have any tooltip or right-click context menu so I haven't been able to identify which process it belongs to. I tried using the "Find Window's Process" tool in [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) but that won't identify individual tray icons.

Short of killing processes until it disappears, is there a good way to identify which process this icon belongs to?

Comment: I wanted to keep the question as general as possible, but if you recognise that specific icon please leave a comment telling me what it is! Thanks.

Comment: I believe it is part of your keyboard drivers.  Try enabling caps lock, and see if the icon changes...

Comment: Maybe check your startup programs to narrow down what it could be?

Comment: Spot on - thanks Francis! If I toggle Caps Lock on then off again it disappears. After that it appears (not always, but a bit haphazardly) when Caps Lock is on. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Use `Control Panel / Notification Area Icons` to identify the icon.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! For Windows 10 users, go to Settings -> Personalisation -> Taskbar -> "Select which icons appear on the taskbar".

Answer (score 3):

Click the up arrow in the system tray, and select Customize. It'll list all the icons and the programs' names.

Comment: @Mark: What is the name of your mysery A icon?

Comment: @FiveO - http://superuser.com/questions/505108/how-can-i-identify-a-mystery-tray-icon-in-windows-7#comment604187_505108 & http://www.sevenforums.com/system-security/246491-strange-try-icon-my-windows-7-any-idea-what.html

Answer (score 1):

This [Windows System Tray Scan Utility](http://exodusdev.com/products/windows-system-tray-scan-utility) may work, though it doesn't mention win7 compatibility.